# Pasar valor del select a php

Tags: javascript, php, html

> Estoy realizando un buscador de boletas con select para año y mes, pero cuando capturo los valores seleccionados no encuentro la forma de pasar los valores concatenados a php. Dejo mi codigo que avance

```
 <select id="meses" name="meses" onchange="getSelectedValue();">
    <option value="01">Enero</option>
    <option value="02">Febrero</option>
    <option value="03">Marzo</option>
  </select>
<script>
    function getSelectedValue(){
        /*OBTIENE VALOR*/
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("meses").value;
        alert(selectedValue);
        /*OBTIENE TEXTO*/
        var combo = document.getElementById("meses");
        var selected = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
        alert(selected);           
    }          
</script>
```

Comment: La mejor forma de pasarlo al servidor es usando Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de JavaScript. Lee sobre el tema en la red y revisa algunas de las preguntas aquí que ya tratan sobre eso. Es algo relativamente fácil de realizar. No obstante, si hay algún problema te ayudaremos cuando tengas el código basado en una de esas dos herramientas.